# Simple identity for inf and sup of inner product

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $V$ be an inner product space, $S \subseteq V$, and $y \in V$.

I believe the following identity is true:
$$
\newcommand{\inner}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}
\inf_{x \in S} \inner{x,y} = -\sup_{x \in S} \inner{x,-y}.
$$

If $S$ satisfies sufficient conditions for the $\arg \min$ to exist (closed, compact?), then it is easy:

Let $x^\star = \arg \min_{x \in S} \inner{x,y}$. Then
$$
\min_{x \in S} \inner{x,y}
= \inner{x^\star, y}
= -\inner{x^\star, -y}
\geq -\max_{x \in S} \inner{x, -y}.
$$
Let $x_\star = \arg \max_{x \in S} \inner{x,-y}$. Then
$$
-\max_{x \in S} \inner{x,-y}
= -\inner{x_\star, -y}
= \inner{x_\star, y}
\geq \min_{x \in S} \inner{x, y}.
$$
But this proof technique cannot be applied version with $\inf$ and $\sup$ because it would require something like $\arg \sup$ to exist.

I believe we can assert the existence of $\arg \sup$ by the continuity of the inner product, if we also require completeness of $V$, and maybe some other conditions that I am forgetting.

However, I think the theorem is still true even if the space is not complete...

Is there a better proof technique that avoids this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is any set of real numbers and $-T$ denotes $\{-x:x\in T\}$ then $\inf T=-\sup (-T)$. Just take $T=\{\langle x, y \rangle  : y \in S\}$.

The only property of inner product you require is $ -\langle x, y \rangle=\langle x, -y \rangle$ and you don't have to know any special property of the set $S$.